# Add own tab in User Preferences

Tags: scripting, customization

How to add own tab in User Preferences? I want to customize some paths in my Blender plugin and gie this ability in User Preferences. How can I get control of User Preferences tabs or if this is not possible, how can I give ability to edit variables in my plugin (I want to have "global" setting, not for each individual project)?

Comment: Most addons preferences are tucked away inside their corresponding entry panel in the addon list

Comment: How to get entry panel hook? Is manual page for it on Blender doc website?